# Command Line Output to a TXT file (Java.exe -version) Returning blank

Tags: command-line, command-prompt

I need to output some information regarding the java.exe verison to a text file.
The command prompt command

```
C:\Windows\System32\Java.exe > C:\Users|txt.txt outputs everything to the correct file.
```

When I try to add the -version

```
C:\Windows\System32\Java.exe -version > C:\Users|txt.txt, the output text file remains blank.
```

Is there a way to get this into a txt file?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use this command line instead:

```
C:\Windows\System32\Java.exe -version 2> C:\Users\txt.txt
```

(note the additional `2`.)

Java is writing the version information to standard error (channel 2) rather than standard output.

Comment: why is that? I mean why the output goes to standard error rather than standard output???

Comment: @opensas: I don't know, but if I had to guess I'd say that stdout is reserved for the Java program itself, so anything from the runtime rather than the program goes to stderr.

Answer (score 3):

The command "java -version" prints its outputs into the standard error.
So, you can redirect those outputs using "2>".