# VB to run Command for java.exe and output text to txt file

Tags: vba, command-line, command-prompt

```
    Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim sCommand as String
    Dim oWrite as System.IO.StreamWriter
    sCommand = "cmd C:\Windows\System32\java.exe -version2> C:\Users\Desktop\version.txt"
    oWrite = IO.File.CreateText(C:\Users\Desktop\version.txt

    End Sub
```

When i run the command in the command prompt it does what it is suppose to do (write to txt file. But when implemented into VB it will run and flash the command prompt but it will not write to a file.

Am I missing a line of something?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Good practice for solving your own question is to actually post your own answer and then accept that (you can accept your own answer after the question has been active for two days) rather than editing your question so that it doesn't actually ask anything. So you might consider rolling the question back to the original or first edit, and then posting what you did as an answer.

Comment: Furthermore, when someone answers a question to your liking (as it looks like they did [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980767/command-line-output-to-a-txt-file-java-exe-version-returning-blank)), click the checkmark next to it to declare it answered. This lets others know the problem has been solved, it gives credit to the person with the best answer, and shows that you're diligent about managing your account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was clearly making things way to complicated...
This ended up working perfectly Fine.

```
    Sub Main()
     Dim sdkCommand As String

    sdkCommand = "C:\Windows\System32\Java.exe -version 2> C:\Users\Desktop\JavaSDKInfo.txt && C:\Windows\System32\tasklist.exe /FI ""IMAGENAME eq java.exe"" >> C:\Users\Desktop\JavaSDKInfo.txt"
    Shell("cmd.exe /c" & sdkCommand)

End Sub
```