# Batch script output to file

Tags: windows-7, batch-file

I am trying to run a small batch file with the following lines to print the output of java version.

```
@echo off
set instDir=%cd%
set JAVA_DIR="%instDir%\bin\jre\bin\java.exe"
%JAVA_DIR% -version > output.txt
```

When I run (double click) this file with "*.bat" extension, nothing is written to the output.txt.

When I execute the same file from command prompt, it prints the version on command prompt, but does not print to the file.

Comment: Got the link to answer Sorry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5980767/command-line-output-to-a-txt-file-java-exe-version-returning-blank

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to redirect the standard output but you need to redirect the error output:

```
@echo off
set instDir=%cd%
set JAVA_DIR="%instDir%\bin\jre\bin\java.exe"
%JAVA_DIR% -version 2> ".\output.txt"
```