# Get the Output of a Java String From VBA

Tags: java, vba

I need to get the output string of a java function into my VBA project. As a fast example, I am trying to get the output of the java version installed but in the real application it will be other private functions.

First attempt:

```
' Needs a reference to Windows Script Host Object Model
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub get_java_output()
    Dim cmd_windows    As New WshShell
    Dim execution_cmd  As WshExec
    Dim command_str    As String
    command_str = "java -version"
    Set execution_cmd = cmd_windows.exec("cmd.exe /c " & command_str)
    Do While execution_cmd.Status = WshRunning
        Sleep 20
    Loop
    final_string = execution_cmd.StdOut.ReadAll
    Debug.Print final_string
End Sub
```

Second attempt:

```
Sub get_java_output_2()
    Dim windows_shell As Object
    
    Set windows_shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    command_str = "java -version"
    shell_output = windows_shell.Run("cmd /c " & command_str & " > c:\temp\output.txt", 0, False)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set File = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\output.txt", 1)
    final_string = File.ReadAll
    File.Close
    Debug.Print final_string
End Sub
```

None of them worked for me.

I would like to avoid the use of temporary files as in my second attempt example. In the final usage, I will call this function hundred of thousand of times, and I prefer not to create that amount of files or edit that file so many times...

Comment: This isn't really related to Java per se. You are trying to capture the output of a process invoked via a shell command. Perhaps one of the answers here might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784367/capture-output-value-from-a-shell-command-in-vba

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution for boths attempts and basically it is the same problem: the output of a java function displayed on the command shell is treated as an error, therefore it is not an output. [The doubt was solved here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5980824/7787606)

In the case of sending the java output to a file, it is solved using `2>` instead of just `>` as it is said [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/redirect-output-from-command-line-to-text-file/). Anyway, there are a lot of different variants depending of what you need, as reported in [this other link](https://askubuntu.com/a/731237). A minor problem of this method is that the creation of the output file needs a time to be done, therefore the final variable of the `Run` command must be settled to `True`

And the code is as follows:

```
Sub get_java_output_2()
    Dim windows_shell As Object
    
    Set windows_shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    command_str = "java -version"
    shell_output = windows_shell.Run("cmd /c " & command_str & " 2> c:\temp\output.txt", 0, True)
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set File = fso.OpenTextFile("c:\temp\output.txt", 1)
    final_string = File.ReadAll
    File.Close
    Debug.Print final_string
End Sub
```

In the case of taking directly the java output to a variable, it is solved using `StdErr` instead of `StdOut`.
I got the illumination reading [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/cpp/redirecting-error-command-prompt). The `WshExec` object has three main elements: `StdErr`, `StdIn` and `StdOut`. If java output string is treated as an error, it should be inside `StdErr` instead.

And the code is as follows:

```
' Needs a reference to Windows Script Host Object Model
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Sub get_java_output()
    Dim cmd_windows    As New WshShell
    Dim execution_cmd  As WshExec
    Dim command_str    As String
    command_str = "java -version"
    Set execution_cmd = cmd_windows.exec(command_str)
    Do While execution_cmd.Status = WshRunning
        Sleep 20
    Loop
    final_string = execution_cmd.StdErr.ReadAll
    Debug.Print final_string
End Sub
```